# Improve assertions

Tags: php, assert

I would like to improve the precondition assertions:

```
function foo($bar) {
    if($bar === null) {
        return;
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

The better solution is the [g_return_if_fail](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Warnings-and-Assertions.html#g-return-if-fail) and [g_return_val_if_fail](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Warnings-and-Assertions.html#g-return-val-if-fail) C macro.

[assert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) seems to be a good alternative, but the execution flow is not broke. Without macro, a solution would be:

```
function foo($bar) {
    assert($bar === null) || return;

    // do stuff
}
```

But the parser dislike this. Have you other ideas? (preferred php version: 5.3).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!assert($bar === null)) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: This is a syntactic fix, but is not easy to read: negative condition and multiline.